# SSLHandshakeException in Android Tests

Tags: java, android, ssl, testing

I have trouble with SSL in android tests. Test looks like

```
@Test
public void requestSettings() throws Exception {
    TestSubscriberBase<Settings> subscriberBase = TestSubscribers.mustHaveResult();
    CommonApi.requestSettings(true).subscribe(subscriberBase);
    System.out.println(subscriberBase.result.text);
}
```

Where method `requestSettings` uses simple `HttpUrlConnection`. Also it works *perfectly in android* app.

When I tried to test https request from Android Studio I`m getting this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at ru.reksoft.platform.api.ApiGate.sendCommonRequest(ApiGate.java:170)
    at ru.reksoft.platform.api.ApiGate.sendRequest(ApiGate.java:121)
    at ru.reksoft.platform.test.TestApiGate.sendRequest(TestApiGate.java:91)
    at ru.reksoft.okey.api.ApiBase$1.call(ApiBase.java:30)
    at ru.reksoft.okey.api.ApiBase$1.call(ApiBase.java:24)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10144)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler$InnerImmediateScheduler.schedule(ImmediateScheduler.java:58)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:45)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10144)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$2.call(OnSubscribeRedo.java:273)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$5.request(OnSubscribeRedo.java:361)
    at rx.internal.producers.ProducerArbiter.setProducer(ProducerArbiter.java:126)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$2$1.setProducer(OnSubscribeRedo.java:267)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo.call(OnSubscribeRedo.java:353)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo.call(OnSubscribeRedo.java:47)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10144)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10144)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10144)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$2.call(OnSubscribeRedo.java:273)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$5.request(OnSubscribeRedo.java:361)
    at rx.internal.producers.ProducerArbiter.setProducer(ProducerArbiter.java:126)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$2$1.setProducer(OnSubscribeRedo.java:267)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo.call(OnSubscribeRedo.java:353)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo.call(OnSubscribeRedo.java:47)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10144)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$2.call(OnSubscribeRedo.java:273)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$5.request(OnSubscribeRedo.java:361)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo.call(OnSubscribeRedo.java:353)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo.call(OnSubscribeRedo.java:47)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10144)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10144)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10144)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10144)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10240)
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10207)
    at ru.reksoft.okey.tests.CommonApiTest.requestSettings(CommonApiTest.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 113 more
```

**What I tried:**

1. Trusting all certificates

   ```
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
       new X509TrustManager() {
           public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
               return new X509Certificate[0];
           }
           public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
           public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
       }};

    HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) { return true; }
    };

   try {
     SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
     sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
     HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
     HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }
   ```
2. Setting system property Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation = false `System.getProperties().setProperty("Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation","false");`

**So what can I do to avoid SSLHandshakeException?**

**P.S.** I don`t want to add certificate because there are a lot of testing urls, so I dont have much time for adding certificate for *every* url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found problem.**

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
```

Looks like these 2 methods **do not work** with android test environment, but work in android application.

So I just passed real `HttpsUrlConnection` instance and set `SSLSocketFactory` and `HostNameVerifier`.

```
public void disableSSLinitDisablingSSL(HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection {
  TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
        }};

  HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) { return true; }
  };

  SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
  sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
  httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
  httpsURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier(hv);
}
```

Comment: tried this but it did not work (tested with API 21 emulator)